# Спецификатор noexcept для функции, вызывающей шаблонный конструктор

Tags: c++, c++11

Есть следующий конструктор в классе:

```
template < typename S, typename V,
           typename Enable = std::enable_if_t < 
    std::is_convertible < std::decay_t < S > *, string_type * > ::value && 
    std::is_convertible < std::decay_t < V > *, vector_type * > ::value > >
Implementation(number_type number, S && string, V && vector) noexcept(true) :
    m_number { std::move (number) },
    m_string { std::forward < S > (string) },
    m_vector { std::forward < V > (vector) }
{}
```

И функция-член `clone()`:

```
Implementation Implementation::clone() const // noexcept(true)
{
    return Implementation(
        this->number(), 
        this->string(),
        this->vector());
}
```

Как правильно в этой функции указывать `noexcept`? Потенциально, при изменении конструктора эта функция может генерировать исключения, но модифицировать ее `noexcept(true)` после обновления конструктора не хочется. Или здесь можно как-то использовать `operator noexcept`? Предполагаю, что проще всего вообще не писать.

Примечание: `this->number()` и т.п. `noexcept`.

Comment: Можно написать `noxcept` оператор, но он будет громоздким, т.к. придётся делать фиктивный вызов конструктора. P.S. функция `clone` выглядит весьма странно, зачем она? Чем обычный конструктор копирования и оператора копирования не угодили?

Comment: Спецификатор `noexcept` по дизайну сделан неправильно. Хотя бы только потому, что он, несмотря на свое название, не дает никаких гарантий по поводу выбрасывания исключений. А его использование обычно подразумевает фактически полное дублирование кода метода. т. е. в данном случае придется писать `noexcept(noexcept(decltype(m_number){std::move (number)}) && noexcept(decltype(m_string){std::forward< S >(string)}) && noexcept(decltype(m_vector){std::forward< V >(vector)}))`, что чревато проблемами, как и любая копипаста.

Comment: @ixSci а можете объяснить смысл использования ф-ии clone() в этом коде: https://github.com/malamanteau/IdiomIMPL/blob/master/Private.hpp ? Функция - см. стр. 239, ее использование в копирующих к-ре и операторе присваивания - см. стр. 123 и 173. Я так понимаю, это для сокращения кода? Раньше просто встречал функцию с именем clone() в основном в полиморфных базовых классах.

Comment: @Jenssen, не могу, я особо смысла в ней не вижу там. `clone`, как Вы уже сами написали, обычно используется в полиморфных классах. Использование этого имени для создания простого объекта только сбивает с толку.

Comment: @ixSci эта функция, видимо, позволяет уменьшить дублирование кода и только. Имя может и не очень удачно. Я оформил часть этого в виде вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/751310/Использование-функции-clone-и-перенаправление-действий-в-перемещающие-специаль?noredirect=1#comment1157834_751310