# Использование функции clone() и перенаправление действий в перемещающие специальные функции-члены

Tags: c++, c++11, оператор-присваивания, конструктор-копирования

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем разница между следующими двумя реализациями:

Вот эта реализация не использует `clone()`-функцию и перемещение:

```
Implementation(const Implementation &  other) :
    m_number { other.numner() },
    m_string { other.string() },
    m_vector { other.vector() }
{}

Implementation& operator=(const Implementation &  other)
{
    if (this == &other) return *this;
    Implementation copy { other };
    this->swap(copy);
    return *this;
}
```

Вот эта реализация использует `clone()` и перенаправляет действия частично в перемещающие конструктор и оператор присваивания:

```
Implementation(const Implementation &  other) :
    Implementation(other.clone())
{}

Implementation(      Implementation && other) noexcept { ... }

Implementation& operator=(const Implementation &  other)
{
    if (this == &other) return *this;
    return operator=(other.clone());
}

Implementation& operator=(      Implementation && other) noexcept { ... }

Implementation clone() const
{
    return Implementation(
        this->number(),
        this->string(),
        this->vector());
}
```

Вторую реализацию я увидел в этом [коде](https://github.com/malamanteau/IdiomIMPL/blob/master/Private.hpp) (он за авторством Скотта Маейрса). См. строки 123, 173, 239. При этом речь, конечно, не идет о полиморфном базовом классе (где иногда можно встретить виртуальную функцию с именем `clone`). Предполагаю, что использование `clone()`-функции сделано для сокращения кода.

**Вопрос** в том, есть ли какой-то конкретный (не стилистический) смысл в копирующих конструкторе и операторе присваивания, которые используют перемещающие конструктор и оператор присваивания?

Comment: Отсутствие копирования кода?

Comment: @Harry, пожалуй, так. А за счет дополнительных вызовов производительность не пострадает? Или мы уповаем на оптимизацию наших компиляторов?

Comment: Да уж такой inline-вариант вызова должен оптимизироваться даже чем-то особо старым, ну, а компиляторы, поддерживающие C++11, по определению *особо* старыми быть не могут :)

Comment: @Harry а что Вы думаете о функции clone? Мне сейчас прокомментировали в другом вопросе, что это имя только сбивает с толку, а лучше использовать в полиморфных классах.

Comment: Откровенно говоря, ничего не думаю :)

Comment: Дык код только удлинился. Было два метода - копирующий конструктор и копирующий оператор присваивания - а теперь еще и `clone`. А при вызове конструктора копирования будет создаваться бесполезный временный объект.

Comment: @VTT да не особо, так если использовать вызов перемещающих из копирующих, как в коде вопроса, то там для создания копии дважды к-р вызывать - а так он в clone один раз фиоурирует. Короче, это у кого какой почерк. Меня только немного волновало лишние вызовы, но учитывая оптимизацию компиляторов об этом можно забыть

Comment: Для создания копии в первом варианте нужно только вызвать конструктор копирования, а во втором будет еще и временный объект. Без поддержки С++17 это гарантированный overhead. А даже с поддержкой - в плане оптимизации тривильный конструктор лучше отдать на откуп компилятору.